# SharePoint in email alerts html tags are displaying?

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, incoming-email

In our SharePoint site based on the End date, email alerts sent to the particular users. Some times without any issues all content was displaying correctly.

But some times the content include HTML tags.This is not happening frequently.

Why is this happening?How to resolve this. ?

```
//my html code only in this below section i am geeting html tags in email
StringBuilder strbBody = new StringBuilder();
strbBody.Append("<tr>");
strbBody.Append("<td height=\"25\" style=\"padding-right:20px;font-family:Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#888;white-space:nowrap; font-style:normal\">" + strTitle + "</td>");
strbBody.Append("<td height=\"25\" style=\"padding-right:10px;font-family:Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#888\">•</td>");
strbBody.Append("<td height=\"25\" style=\"padding-right:10px; font-size:13px; color:#222\"; margin:0=\"margin:0\" 0 0.3em 0;\">" + strValue + "</td>");
strbBody.Append("<td height=\"25\" style=\"padding-right:10px; font-size:13px;color:#222; margin:0 0 0.3em;\">" + strValue + "</td>");
strbBody.Append("</tr>");
```

[image]